# When does gradle store in .m2 and when in cache?

Tags: gradle

In which scenario will gradle store artifacts in the directory `.m2` and in which scenario will it store them in `gradle\caches`?

I am trying to resolve my issue wherein I have a dependency within my local build

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Gradle will *read* from your local maven repository only when you declare it as a valid repository:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Gradle will *write* to your local maven repository only when you publish artifacts and tell it to publish to the local maven repo.

- If you are using the `maven` plugin, when [executing the task `install`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sub:installing_to_the_local_repository)
- If you are using the `maven-publish` plugin, when [executing the task `publishToMavenLocal`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:install)

Gradle will use its own internal cache for *all* resolved dependencies, including ones coming from the local maven repository.

For example, if you use a dependency `org:foo:1.0` from your maven local repository, the metadata and artifact will be copied to the Gradle cache on first resolution. From then on, the dependency will be resolved from the Gradle cache.

However, if the dependency is changing, such as when using a `-SNAPSHOT` version, the Gradle cache will by default keep the last one resolved for 24h. After which it will perform a new resolution, hitting again the local maven repository in this example.

See [the documentation for controlling that cache duration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dynamic_versions.html) for dynamic and/or changing dependencies.

Comment: The documentation has [moved](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Gradle_User_Guide.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/userguide/troubleshooting_dependency_resolution.html#sub:dynamic_versions_and_changing_modules)