# publish a builded project using gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm building a project locally using gradle build, however I'm not finding the jar in the local gradle repository

```
~.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1...
```

How I can say to gradle to publish the builded jar ?

maven do the same with `mvn install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takes some time to get used to gradle when coming from maven.

Basically gradle can publish to your local maven repo and also look for artifacts there.

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196867/when-does-gradle-store-in-m2-and-when-in-cache) for the details.